# yum check update returning multiple versions in order

Tags: yum, update

Will yum check-update return list of available versions to be upgraded to in some order (ascending or descending).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would use `yum list updates` for that. It will only show latest available versions of packages that can be upgraded. There is no particular order of the output.

If you would like to upgrade a package to a specific version, you can check which versions are present in the repository using the following command:

```
yum list --showduplicates <packagename>
```